# no log file produced

Tags: python, logging

I'm new to logging in Python and have tried to build a basic logger that writes to a file.  The problem I have is that the file is not created, yet there are not any errors thrown.  Any ideas?

Using Spyder IDE in Anaconda (in case that is applicable)

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import logging

format = "%(asctime)s %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.DEBUG, filename='H://logfile.log')

now = pd.datetime.now()
logging.info("Time Created")
```

Comment: Your code works on my machine... Are you sure you have permission to write to H: ?

Comment: .to_csv will write to H.  Maybe something unique with logging??

Comment: Just did some quick research since it worked for you all...  It's a Spyder IDE problem.

Comment: Interesting I have Spyder IDE on my machine too...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using python 2.7.11 on osx, I reproduced your steps as also explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html)

```
import logging
format = "%(asctime)s %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(format=format, level=logging.DEBUG, filename='logfile.log')
logging.info("Hello World")
```

A file named logfile.log is created in directory from which I executed python.

You can check the dir in which python is running typing:

```
pwd
```

My guess is that there is a problem with the permission of the folder in which you want to create the log file, or in the way you are writing the absolute path of the folder.

I would advise you to create first a log file in the local dir ( which is the output of the pwd command ) and see if this works.

Answer (score -1):

Appears the problem is with Spyder IDE v. 2.3.8 (maybe mine is outdated).  The log file is created in command prompt but in Spyder the log file isn't created.

Comment: Could you post a link to your findings for future reference?

Comment: Not much of an answer. What information can you provide to back up your claim?

Comment: Are you saying the problem only occurs when you execute the code through Spyder, but not with IDLE?

Comment: Trying to do more testing to see if it works outside of Spyder.  Here is the github issue: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2572